# To what altitudes does cosmic radiation penetrate?

Tags: radiation, earth

How far does high energy ([Cosmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray)) radiation penetrate(km above sea level) into the planet earth? And at what rate(/m^2/s)? (limited set of rates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Cosmic-ray_flux))
(The [Aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora) is low energy protons that stop at 90 to 150 km)

Maximums for ranges in the [Electromagnetic spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) (1×10^-16 eV - 1×10^6 eV)
and various [Particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_particles) (including [UHCER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-energy_cosmic_ray)) ( - 1×10^19 eV). Incomplete table:

```
Type           | eV(@~C) | rate    | penetration
------------------------------------------------
Fermion        |         |         | 
 Neutrino      |         |         | -1x10^4
Quark          |         |         | 
Lepton         |         |         | 
 Electron      |         |         | 
Boson          |         |         | 
 Photon        |         |         | 
  Ionizing     | 1x10^6  |         | 
  Visible      | 12      | 1x10^13 | 0
  Radio        | 1x10^-3 |         | 
Composite      |         |         | 
 Baryon        |         |         | 
  Neutron      |         |         | 
  Proton       | 1×10^9  |         | 
 Meson         | -       | -       | (Half-life < 1s )
 Atomic nuclei |         |         | 
  Fe           | 1×10^20 | 1×10^−9 | 80?
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does "high energy" mean? Penetration obviously depends on energy. What about airshowers? Are you just interested in the primary particles. As it stands, this is too broad. A lot of things make it to the ground.

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm interested in an overview of what makes it to the ground, with focus on abundantce and high eV. As there are 'a lot' I am grouping by type and only listing the abundant or high energy. I could break this into many similar questions, but I think they would mostly share citations so I think the table is more suitable. If you could provided a refrence for 'a lot' that would help.

Comment: Well, all neutrinos for a start.

Comment: Yes well most make it right through that's why there is a number in that cell already, but I'm not sure of the eV or rate for that row.